# parallelizing in openMP

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following code that I want to paralleize using OpenMP

```
for(m=0; m<r_c; m++)
{
    for(n=0; n<c_c; n++)
    {
        double value = 0.0;
        for(j=0; j<r_b; j++)
            for(k=0; k<c_b; k++)
            {
                double a;
                if((m-j)<0 || (n-k)<0 || (m-j)>r_a || (n-k)>c_a)
                    a = 0.0;
                else
                    a = h_a[((m-j)*c_a) + (n-k)];
                //printf("%lf\t", a);
                value += h_b[(j*c_b) + k] * a;
            }
        h_c[m*c_c + n] = value;
        //printf("%lf\t", h_c[m*c_c + n]);
    }
    //cout<<"row "<<m<<" completed"<<endl;
}
```

In this I want every thread to perform "for j" and "for k" simultaneouly.
I am trying to do using pragma omp parallel for before the "for m" loop but not getting the correct result.
How can I do this in an optimized manner. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you get and what you expect?

Comment: @AviGinsburg its the code for matrix 2D full convolution and i am trying that each thread perform the 'j' and 'k' loops in parallel. on doing so I am getting the correct result but the execution time is getting more than doubled. I am not able to figure out the problem

Answer (score 1):

Depending exactly from which loop you want to parallelize, you have three options:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp for    // Option #1
    for(m=0; m<r_c; m++)
    {
        for(n=0; n<c_c; n++)
        {
            double value = 0.0;
#pragma omp for    // Option #2
            for(j=0; j<r_b; j++)
                for(k=0; k<c_b; k++)
                {
                    double a;
                    if((m-j)<0 || (n-k)<0 || (m-j)>r_a || (n-k)>c_a)
                        a = 0.0;
                    else
                        a = h_a[((m-j)*c_a) + (n-k)];
                    //printf("%lf\t", a);
                    value += h_b[(j*c_b) + k] * a;
                }
                h_c[m*c_c + n] = value;
                //printf("%lf\t", h_c[m*c_c + n]);
        }
        //cout<<"row "<<m<<" completed"<<endl;
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Option #3
for(m=0; m<r_c; m++)
{
    for(n=0; n<c_c; n++)
    {
#pragma omp parallel
            {
            double value = 0.0;
#pragma omp for
            for(j=0; j<r_b; j++)
                for(k=0; k<c_b; k++)
                {
                    double a;
                    if((m-j)<0 || (n-k)<0 || (m-j)>r_a || (n-k)>c_a)
                        a = 0.0;
                    else
                        a = h_a[((m-j)*c_a) + (n-k)];
                    //printf("%lf\t", a);
                    value += h_b[(j*c_b) + k] * a;
                }
            h_c[m*c_c + n] = value;
            //printf("%lf\t", h_c[m*c_c + n]);
        }
    }
    //cout<<"row "<<m<<" completed"<<endl;
}
```

Test and profile each. You might find that option #1 is fastest if there isn't a lot of work for each thread, or you may find that with optimizations on, there is no difference (or even a slowdown) when enabling OMP.

### Edit

I've adopted the MCVE supplied in the comments as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <omp.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#define W_OMP
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<double> h_a(9);
    std::generate(h_a.begin(), h_a.end(), std::rand);
    int r_b = 500;
    int c_b = r_b;
    std::vector<double> h_b(r_b * c_b);
    std::generate(h_b.begin(), h_b.end(), std::rand);
    int r_c = 500;
    int c_c = r_c;
    int r_a = 3, c_a = 3;
    std::vector<double> h_c(r_c * c_c);

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

#ifdef W_OMP
#pragma omp parallel 
    {
#endif
        int m,n,j,k;
#ifdef W_OMP
#pragma omp for 
#endif
        for(m=0; m<r_c; m++)
        {
            for(n=0; n<c_c; n++)
            {
                double value = 0.0,a;
                for(j=0; j<r_b; j++)
                {
                    for(k=0; k<c_b; k++)
                    {
                        if((m-j)<0 || (n-k)<0 || (m-j)>r_a || (n-k)>c_a)
                            a = 0.0;
                        else a = h_a[((m-j)*c_a) + (n-k)];
                        value += h_b[(j*c_b) + k] * a;
                    }
                }
                h_c[m*c_c + n] = value;
            }
        }
#ifdef W_OMP
    }
#endif
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << elapsed.count() << "ms"
#ifdef W_OMP
        "\t with OMP"
#else
        "\t without OMP"
#endif
        "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

As a reference, I'm using VS2012 (OMP 2.0, grrr). I'm not sure when `collapse` was introduced, but apparently after 2.0. Optimizations were /O2 and compiled in Release x64.

### Benchmarks

Using the original sizes of the loops (7,7,5,5) and therefore arrays, the results were `0ms` without OMP and `1ms` with. Verdict: optimizations were better, and the added overhead wasn't worth it. Also, the measurements are not reliable (too short).

Using the slightly larger sizes of the loops (100, 100, 100, 100) and therefore arrays, the results were about equal at about `108ms`. Verdict: still not worth the naive effort, tweaking OMP parameters might tip the scale. Definitely not the x4 speedup I would hope for.

Using an even larger sizes of the loops (500, 500, 500, 500) and therefore arrays, OMP started to pull ahead. Without OMP `74.3ms`, with `15s`. Verdict: Worth it. Weird. I got a x5 speedup with four threads and four cores on an i5. I'm not going to try and figure out how that happened.

### Summary

As has been stated in countless answers here on SO, it's not always a good idea to parallelize every `for` loop you come across. Things that can screw up your desired xN speedup:

1. Not enough work per thread to justify the overhead of creating the additional threads
2. The work itself is memory bound. This means that the CPU can be running at 1petaHz and you still won't see a speedup.
3. Memory access patterns. I'm not going to go there. Feel free to edit in the relevant info if you want it.
4. OMP parameters. The best choice of parameters will often be a result of this entire list (not including this item, to avoid recursion issues).
5. SIMD operations. Depending on what and how you're doing, the compiler may vectorize your operations. I have no idea if OMP will usurp the SIMD operations, but it is possible. Check your assembly (foreign language to me) to confirm.

Comment: I am using the first option and specifying the number of threads as 4 I am getting the current output but the execution time is getting more than double.

Comment: @ManishKhilnani If all the results are the same, the last paragraph holds the key. If there isn't enough work being done (or if it's a memory bound problem) then parallelizing isn't going to help, and may even hurt. There are a plethora of questions on SO about OMP hurting performance. If you make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll look deeper into it.

Comment: I don't want the whole code, just the MCVE. Just a `main()` which loads all the data and starts the convolution. The data can be synthetic so that they don't have to be explicitly loaded.

Comment: 'int main()
{ double h_a[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
 double h_b[25] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
 double h_c[49];
 int r_c = 7,c_c = 7, r_a = 3, c_a = 3, r_b = 5,c_b = 5;
 int m,n,j,k;
 for(m=0; m<r_c; m++)
 {
  for(n=0; n<c_c; n++)
  {
   double value = 0.0,a;
   for(j=0; j<r_b; j++)
   { 
    for(k=0; k<c_b; k++)
    {   
       
     if((m-j)<0 || (n-k)<0 || (m-j)>r_a || (n-k)>c_a)
      a = 0.0;
     else
      a = h_a[((m-j)*c_a) + (n-k)];
     value += h_b[(j*c_b) + k] * a;
    }
   }
   h_c[m*c_c + n] = value;
  }
 }
}'

Comment: I am using #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4) private(m,n,j,k) collapse(2) before the "for m" loop

Comment: Two things: 1) `mc_c` and `jc_b` are not defined; 2) are the loop lengths in your program also 7,7,5 & 5? If so, the loop is too short to be worth parallelizing. The overhead associated with OMP is more than the calculation itself (see last paragraph of my answer).

Comment: no the loop length in my actual program are 1000,1000,100 and 100 respectively. and for each 1000*1000 element it is doing 100*100 multiplication and addition. what I gave above is just a way of how I am doing things and what I want to parallelize.

Comment: Using those numbers I get `10s` and `2.7s`, almost x4 speedup. What compiler and compiler flags are you using?

Comment: on trying out the code that you have posted above I am getting a speedup, not as great as yours but I am getting a speedup, however when I am entering the 2 matrices from an external file I am not getting a speedup. strange but I am not able to figure out y this is happening, I am using GCC version 4.8.2

Comment: yes tried that also..still when entering the matrices through a seperate file the program is slower when run on openmp and faster when run serially.

Comment: Well, then you have not supplied enough information for someone else to answer the question. If you want more help, you will have to upload the files somewhere and update your question using the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30635053/edit).